# How can I get email updates for questions that are tagged with all tags in a certain set of tags?

Tags: feature-request

At https://stackexchange.com/filters, I would like to create a filter, in order to get email updates for questions that use *both* the `haskell` and the `stack` tags.

It appears that currently I can only create a filter that will show results for *either* of the tags.

For context: Most of the questions that use both tags are mistagged, and should use the `haskell-stack` tag instead of `stack`. If anyone can point me at a tool to help fixing these tags, I'd be glad to hear about it!

---

Original paragraphs based on imperfect obervation (see comments):

When I enter `[haskell] [stack]` into the "Just questions tagged with" prompt and preview the filtered questions, the results contain questions that use *either* of the tags.

This is inconsistent with the tag search where https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell+stack will only show question that use *both* tags.

Comment: Are you doing these tags for one site or for all sites?

Comment: For all sites, although stackoverflow would be enough.

Comment: Oh, I'm under the impression that the prompt will only accept only one tag, and ignore any following tags. So `[haskell] [stack]` will only filter for `[haskell]`…

Comment: I have started to use https://visualping.io/ to monitor that set of tags.